# How to mount partition like KDEConnect does?

Tags: kde-connect

When in KDEConnect you press "Browse this device" it mounts the partition via sftp if not yet mounted.

How to do this programatically so I can always have device mounted and no press this automatically?

I've tried to mount similarly like KDEConnect does after pressing the "Browser this device" button:

```
$ mount | grep kdeconnect
kdeconnect@192.168.1.51:/ on /run/user/1000/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx type fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

So crafted this command:

```
mkdir -p /run/user/1000/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
sudo mount -v -t fuse.sshfs \
  -o rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000 \
  kdeconnect@192.168.1.51:/ /run/user/1000/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

But it results in the following error:

```
read: Connection reset by peer
```

Alternatively, is it possible to simply trigger KDEConnect to mount partition if not mounted? There it a `kdeconnect-cli` console tool but it misses such options.

Comment: If you're using `sshfs`, you could just use the `sshfs` command instead of `mount -t fuse.sshfs`. I think the `mount` command being run as root maybe causing it to miss your user's SSH config.

Answer (score 5):

The error happens because that command tries to connect to port 22 of your phone and uses *your* SSH keys. In order to mount the filesystem exposed by KDE Connect, you should use its port and SSH keys.

On my phone, that port is `1740` (you can check if yours is the same running `netstat` on your computer). And KDE Connect key is at `~/.config/kdeconnect/privateKey.pem` in my system.

So you should be able to perform the mount with a command such as:

```
sshfs -o rw,nosuid,nodev,identityfile=$HOME/.config/kdeconnect/privateKey.pem,port=1740 kdeconnect@PHONE_IP:/ MOUNT_POINT
```

Remember to replace `PHONE_IP` and `MOUNT_POINT` accordingly. Also notice that I'm using `sshfs` instead of `mount` because it allows easier mounting for a non-privileged user.

More info [here](https://rafaelc.org/blog/mounting-kde-connect-filesystem-via-cli/).

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the daemon of KDE Connect (if running, but I assume it will in your case) to mount it for you using D-Bus:

```
busctl --user call org.kde.kdeconnect /modules/kdeconnect/devices/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/sftp org.kde.kdeconnect.device.sftp mountAndWait
```

`busctl` comes with systemd, so this should already be installed on a normal Ubuntu installation ([man page of `busctl`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/systemd/busctl.1.en.html)), but other tools for executing D-Bus methods from CLI exist as well.

(You may inspect what further methods are available on D-Bus by using UI tools like [D-Feet](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DFeet))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).